# Java 8 how to obtain stream instance with max value

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have a class called `Control`, and another one which is `CLCControl` (this one extends `Control`) and has an attribute called `objective` (float).

I have a `Step` class, which contains a `Control`.

I want to obtain from a `Step` stream, the one which has the `CLCControl` with the maximum `objective` attribute value.

This is what I tried so far

```
stepTableView.getItems().stream().filter(step -> step.getControl() instanceof CLCControl).map(CLCControl.class::cast).max();
```

Comment: In order to find the largest of something you need to be able to order them. Objects by default are not comparable and therefore cannot be ordered without e.g. a comparator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the attribute to `double` and find the `max` as:

```
.stream()
.filter(step -> step.getControl() instanceof CLCControl)
.map(CLCControl.class::cast)
.mapToDouble(Control::getObjective) // << here or `CLCControl::getObjective` for sub class
.max();
```

If you were to find the `Step` with this max objective, you can perrfora comparison as:

```
Step maxObjectiveStep = stepTableView.stream()
        .filter(step -> step.getControl() instanceof CLCControl)
        .max((o1, o2) -> Float.compare(o1.getControl().getObjective(), o2.getControl().getObjective()))
        .orElse(null); // some default
```